# is it possible to retrieve engine value from a sql alchemy session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

First I create a session as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
some_engine = create_engine('my_engine_string')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
session = Session()
```

Then I send this session as an argument to a method

```
def example(session):
    print("you created a session!")
```

Is it possible to get the value of `some_engine` from `session` inside the `example` method? without actually passing `some_engine` or `my_engine_string` to `example` method.

Something as below:

```
def example(session):
   print("you created a session!")
   engine = <using session get the value of `some_engine`>
   print("the engine is retrieved from session")
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[`Session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session)s have the [`.get_bind()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get_bind) method which in your case will return your [`Engine`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) instance.

> Relevant excerpt from the [`sqlalchemy docs`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/):
>
> > Return a “bind” to which this [`Session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session) is bound.
> >
> > The “bind” is usually an instance of [`Engine`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine), except in the case where
> > the [`Session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session) has been explicitly bound directly to a [`Connection`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection).

Thus your `example()` function could do something like:

```
def example(session):
   print("you created a session!")
   engine = session.get_bind()
   print("the engine is retrieved from session")
```